# Property getter typed on Supertype instead of Implementation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have two classes, a `Base`and a `Impl`which extends `Base`.

```
package mypackage

open class Base
class Impl : Base()
```

How would I create a **private property for the concrete `Impl`-Type (for internal use)**, with a **public getter typed as the `Base`-Type**, to achieve polymorphism? My initial approach was like this:

```
class Test {
    private val myType = Impl()
        get():Base
}
```

However, the Kotlin compiler complains:

*Error:(30, 11) Kotlin: Getter return type must be equal to the type of the property, i.e. 'mypackage.Impl'*

Basically, this is what it would look like in plain Java:

```
public class Test {
    private Impl myImpl = new Impl();

    public Base getBase() {
        return myImpl;
    }
}
```

How could one achieve this? Am I missing something?

P.S. I am aware of Backing Fields and creating custom methods as a workaround for getter, I was just curious on how to approach this in an elegant, Kotlin style manner.

Comment: Polymorphism is about not knowing the subclasses. You're achieving the opposite of polymorphism by explicitly defining the type of the getter.

Comment: Please read carefully, I want the getter to return the base type, not the implementation.

Comment: @cypressious sorry for maybe being unclear, I edited and explicitely added that the property with the implementation should be private, only the getter with the base type should be public

Comment: You have a lot of options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34625698/3679676

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the property is private, so will be the getter. In this case, it doesn't matter what type it will have. If you want to have a public property of base type, you'll need to declare it separately:

```
private val _myType = Impl()

public val myType : Base
    get() = _myType
```

Comment: Thank you, somehow I forgot about my own question. From a distance, it is now clear to me. I think I was not aware at that time that properties don't exactly work like member variables. So yes, point taken is that if the property is private, so will be the getter.

Answer (score 2):

You would code this the same as you did in Java, using two different properties.  Unless you are ok with `Impl` never being specialized in the class.  So here are many options:

```
// if you don't need Impl typed as Impl then just hold it as base
class Test1 {
    public val base: Base = Impl()
}

// have both with pointing one reference at the other
class Test2 {
    private val _impl = Impl()
    public val base: Base = _impl
}

// have both, second one is a getter (no real benefit over Test2)
class Test3 {
    private val _impl = Impl()
    public val base: Base
       get() = _impl
}

// use a function to do basically a cast
class Test4 {
    private val _impl = Impl()
    public fun asBase(): Base = _impl
}
```

Or don't worry about this other property, any use of grabbing the Impl can hold it as type Base:

```
class Test5 {
    public val impl: Impl = Impl()
}

// later
val thing: Base = Test5().impl
```

Maybe you are looking to build this in a way with a common interface to get the base implementation?

```
open class Base {}

// a common way to get the implementation from within a class
interface Based {
    val base: Base
}

class ImplAbc : Base()
class ImplXyz : Base()

class TestAbc : Based {
    override val base: Base = ImplAbc()
}

class TestXyz : Based {
    private val _impl = ImplXyz()
    override val base: Base = _impl
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and the thorough answer! I don't know my exact usecase at that time anymore. Anyway, your Test2/Test3 seems to fulfill the requirements I was after (private implementation, public getter typed as base), and, as it is basically the same as cypressious answer above, I hope you don't mind if I mark his answer as green, but give you an upvote and kudos for being helpful :)

Comment: All good, its not about the points, but about making sure when other people read this they have good coverage and content.  @cypressious does good work!  Thanks!

Comment: @JaysonMinard This situation comes up a lot in android/kotlin dev using observable.  The view model has a private mutable-observable, and exposes a public immutable-observable.  The mutable-observable is a subtype of the immutable observable.  I've seen the Test3 option used to address the situation.  I was just trying to see if I could do the same thing using a delegate but no cigar :-)